# WildFly: missing org.jboss.security-module in version 26.0.0

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am trying to get singe sign-on to work with WildFly-prevew 26.0.1. I found a tutorial [WildFly Elytron - Add Kerberos Authentication To Existing Web Application](http://darranl.blogspot.com/2017/09/wildfly-elytron-add-kerberos.html) by Darran Lofthouse.

After it did not work I searched for further resources and found [How to Set Up SSO for JBoss EAP with Kerberos](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/how_to_set_up_sso_with_kerberos/how_to_set_up_sso_for_jboss_eap_with_kerberos). There is a *JBoss Negotiation Toolkit* mentioned. It is said that yout should use the same version of the toolkit as the *JBoss Negotiation included in JBoss EAP* (`EAP_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/security/negotiation/main/module.xml`).

Sadly I did not find the folder `EAP_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/security/negotiation` in the Wildfly 26.0.1-preview. At first I thought that it may be an JBoss EAP feature not included in WildFly. But actually the folder is included in WildFly 24.0.1. Starting with version 25.0.0, the folder is missing. And starting with version 26.0.0.Beta, the whole `EAP_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/security` folder is missing.

So my question is weather this is a bug or a *feature* (maybe it migrated to another module). And if it is a bug, may it be a reason my single sign-on is not working?

Comment: Is there a method to add this module into Wildfly version 26.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

In a WildFly 25 release post (https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/10/05/WildFly25-Final-Released/) it is said that

> We deprecated the use of legacy security long ago and in the WildFly 25 release we have removed support for it.

Most probably that is the reason these packages are missing.